# Grails remoteform file download

Tags: grails, download

Hi am having this remote form. I have 2 submit button one to view and one to download.

```
  <g:formRemote id="myForm" name="myForm" on404="alert('not found!')" update="updateMe"
                      url="[controller: 'crawler', action:'viewdata']" 
                before="if( validateForm( this ) ) { " after="}"       >
```

I'm trying to let user download excel but my div get updated.

```
            response.setContentType("application/octet-stream") 
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=${msg+".xls"}")
    response.outputStream << file.bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is switching your `remoteForm` to a classic `form` and add only the preview action as an Ajax call using the `<g:submitToRemote update="updateMe" />` tag. So that the document you want to download won't be in your `updateMe` div.

Documentation on [submitToRemote](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html).

Comment: yepp, as far as I know it's not possible to load binary data (be it a pdf or some other file) within a <div/> tag. also, it's not so trivial to handle binary data with JavaScript. so, I totally agree with you @BenoitWickramarachi - the best would be to use a classic `form` tag for download...